# How to left-aling formulas and not center them in jupyter notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, mathjax, katex

I would like to know how to left-align formulas in jupyter notebooks and I would also like the formulas not to be centered, but to start at the left edge of the notebook.
I've already read many questions on the subject, but they all focus on saying how to align the formulas to the left, without explaining how to put them not centered.

This is what I have found so far:

```
$$
\begin{aligned}
& [-0.675\sigma - 1.5*(0.675\sigma-(-0.675\sigma)), 0.675\sigma + 1.5*(0.675\sigma-(-0.675\sigma))] =\\
& [-0.675\sigma - 2.025\sigma, 0.675\sigma + 2.025\sigma] =\\
& [ - 2.7\sigma, + 2.7\sigma]\\
\end{aligned}
$$
```

And this is what I get:

[image: Centered formulas]

How can I make them not centered?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of MathJax Jupyter Noebook uses, but if you are using v3, you can use the `flalign` environment to do left alignment:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>

\begin{flalign}
\,&[-0.675\sigma - 1.5*(0.675\sigma-(-0.675\sigma)), 0.675\sigma + 1.5*(0.675\sigma-(-0.675\sigma))] =&\\
\,&[-0.675\sigma - 2.025\sigma, 0.675\sigma + 2.025\sigma] =& \\
\,&[-2.7\sigma, + 2.7\sigma]&
\end{flalign}
```

Note that the first column has to be non-empty, which is why I put in the small spaces.